# angular ng-view phonegap is not working

Tags: android, cordova, angularjs, angular-routing

I am trying to make basic app with angularjs and phonegap in android. But it doesn't seem to be working. Below are my source code files:

index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="main-app">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="body-content" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div class="loader-ajax" ng-show="isViewLoading"></div>
    <div ng-view></div>
</div>
    <script src="js/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.3.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            app.initialize();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

main.js

```
var mobileApp = angular.module("main-app", []);

mobileApp.config(function ($routeProvider,$compileProvider) {

    $routeProvider
        .when("/",
        {
            templateUrl: "partial/home.html",
            controller: "homeController"
        })
        .when("/home",
        {
            templateUrl: "partial/home.html",
            controller: "homeController"
        });
    $compileProvider.urlSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|file|tel):/);
});
mobileApp.controller("MainCtrl",function($scope){
    alert('Coming here');
    $scope.isViewLoading=true;
});
mobileApp.controller("homeController",function($scope){
    alert('Home Coming here');

});
```

index.js

```
var app = {
    initialize: function() {
        this.bind();
    },
    bind: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.deviceready, false);
    },
    deviceready: function() {
        // note that this is an event handler so the scope is that of the event
        // so we need to call app.report(), and not this.report()
        app.report('deviceready');
        angular.bootstrap(document, ['main-app']);
    },
    report: function(id) { 
        console.log("report:" + id);
    }
};
```

When the app is getting load, router doesn't seem to work as its not getting into Homecontroller.

From what I have ready everywhere else, this code should work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://briantford.com/blog/angular-phonegap.html

Comment: @SimonMacDonald hey man I tried that tutorial and for some reason it didn't work (the yaoman instructions where kind of out of date?).. anyways do you know of any github repo or something like that that has a finished phonegap/angularjs project done? that would be a good way to start!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem, which I just found a solution to. Take a look at [Angular ng-view/routing not working in PhoneGap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15105910/angular-ng-view-routing-not-working-in-phonegap)

Answer (score 0):

Move  `app.initialize();` to [PhoneGap's deviceready event](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#deviceready)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem - I was stuck on it for 3 evenings - eventually I compared the template names in the routing to the actual file names - make sure the case matches.