# AngularJS routing not working properly in PhoneGap

Tags: angularjs, cordova, angular-routing

I have been beating my head against the wall trying to figure out why angularJS routing won't work in phonegap for me. I have all the files setup correctly and i don't receive any errors. I'm trying to change the url using the $location.url service directly from angular. So when you tap on a div the controller will have $location.url("profile") for example and nothing will happen. I tried the solution found in this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15627536/angular-ng-view-phonegap-is-not-working) but that's not working for me. Am I doing something wrong, or is there a better way to be approaching this? Following is the routing I have setup

```
var app = angular.module("App", ["hmTouchevents"])
.config(function($routeProvider) {

$routeProvider
    .when("/index.html", {
        templateUrl: "/views/login.html",
        controller: "loginCtlr"
    })
    .when("/landing", {
        templateUrl: "/views/landing.html",
        controller: "landingCtlr"
    })
    .when("/single-view/:id", {
        templateUrl: "/views/single-view.html",
        controller: "singleViewCtlr"
    })
    .when("/restaurant", {
        templateUrl: "/views/restaurant-info.html",
        controller: "restaurantCtlr"
    })
    .when("/profile/:id", {
        templateUrl: "/views/profile.html",
        controller: "profileCtlr"
    })
    .when("/lists/:list", {
        templateUrl: "/views/lists.html",
        controller: "listsCtlr"
    })
    .when("/follow/:type", {
        templateUrl: "/views/follow.html",
        controller: "followCtlr"
    });

});
```

A sample controller would be:

```
app.controller("listsCtlr", ["$scope", "$location", function($scope, $location){

$scope.goTo("profile");

}]);
```

As always any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried e.g. `$location.url("#/profile")`?

Comment: i have and still no dice. the url seems to be changing fine, but angular doesn't seem to grab the template and place it in the ngview.

Comment: did you try to use the html5mode?

Comment: if you put an 'otherwise' route in does it get matched to that route?

Comment: I was finally able to figure out. what i have to do is use the window.location and get the root directory. since phonegap is pulling the index file from file:// then i have to get that absolute path and use it in front of the templateUrl. so i created a global property that saves the root path and changed all the templateUrl's to templateUrl: global.root + pathtofile and it worked like a charm

Comment: @selanac82 any chance you could provide your solution as an answer so that others can see it?

Comment: Have you tried removing the slash from the beginning of the templateUrls?

Answer (score 4):

I had a problem similar to this tonight. The core issue here is that PhoneGap doesn't have a web server built in. If you're developing locally, you probably are using a web server, so you can do something like: `http://localhost/#/profile` and the routing will work.

However, PhoneGap loads your code with a `file://` URL, not `http://`. If you do `$location.url("profile")` you're replacing the entire URL with just `file://profile`, which doesn't exist. Same thing if you use a link like this: `<a href="/#/profile">My Profile</a>`

The solution is to somehow get your links to point to the right place. If you're using `$location.url()` you can prefix it with your file path: `$location.url( window.location + "#/profile" )`

If you're just making a link, you should be able to get away with taking off the leading slash to make it a relative URL: `<a href="/#/profile">My Profile</a>` becomes `<a href="#/profile">My Profile</a>`

Answer (score 4):

Had the exact same issue... I was able to fix this easily by adding the following code to the head of my index.html file.

```
<base href="/android_asset/www/" />
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This worked for me as well, will this (as in do I need a similar fix for iOS) work on iOS? Don't have a mac, so hard to test this at the moment.

Comment: @KungWaz I have not tried this on iOS. I do believe that the base is not `/android_asset/` in iOS, so I would check the logs to see where the page is loaded from, and then just switch the base tag to the `www` folder.

Answer (score 0):

in your controller try...

```
$location.path('/profile');
```

Answer (score 0):

After much tinkering, here's what worked for me!

If you can use $location.path() within the controller, it should work as expected, but if you need to use href-style links, you can build the links off the angular "base" page (e.g. main.html):

`<a href="main.html#/profile">Link To Profile</a>`