# phonegap angularjs route nog working

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, windows-phone-8

I have tried a lot of thing to get routing working in angularjs.
I have tried this:
[Angular ng-view/routing not working in PhoneGap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15105910/angular-ng-view-routing-not-working-in-phonegap)
and google all over the place but couln't get it to working.

i have my code on github https://github.com/rovox/rocinfoapp. All I get to see is a black topbar and the word test which is hardcoded into the index.html i can't get the homepage to show up?

Do you guys have any idea how to get this working?

Greeting

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need to assign a controller to to each .when statement like:

```
 .when('/home', {
     templateUrl: 'partials/home.html'
     controller: MainCtrl
 })
```

I think that currently the code does not know which controller to use for each page. It would also be easier to help you if you provided a plunker or fiddle of your problem, as right now it is a little hard to follow and to diagnose your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have **MainCtrl and ViewCtrl** in **App.controllers** but in your [app.js](https://github.com/rovox/rocinfoapp/blob/master/www/js/app.js) you aren't providing any controller to the routes you're defining. Assign them.

Btw, does that app work locally without PhoneGap?

Comment: But i Will try to add a controller, It does not matter of that controller is empty?

Comment: I don't know, i use ui-router with states (from angular ui) instead of angular-router, but give it a try and tell us if it solved. If not, i'll try it myself tonight

Comment: I ended up rewriting the hole app with using angular-phonegap-seed as the basic and now its working but I can't find the problem I had. If i copy and past my old code back in it stop working. Still looking for the problem.