# How can I fix the angular.js routing in my app?

Tags: angularjs, html, url-routing, angular-routing, ngroute

I'm writing an application on mobile platform steroids, angular.js and firebase.js. Recently I've faced such problem: the page does not load, because it is trying to access a strange url `file://file:///Users/patutinskijfedor/Desktop/firebase/WILLY/www/`.

```
Error: Failed to execute 'replaceState' on 'History': A history state object with URL 'file://file:///Users/patutinskijfedor/Desktop/firebase/WILLY/www/' cannot be created in a document with origin 'null'.
```

I read about this issue in the Internet and realized that my problem is with the routing in angular. It look like this (file `app.js`):

```
angular.module('SCBI', ['SCBI.controllers','ngRoute']).config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    $routeProvider.when('/teachers',{ templateUrl: 'teachers.html'});
    $routeProvider.when('/teachers/:id', {templateUrl: 't.html', controller: 'TeachersListController'});
    $routeProvider.when('/', {templateUrl: 'authorization.html', controller: 'AuthorizationController'});
    $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo:'/'});
});
```

So the problem might be with `html5Mode`. My question is: how can I fix the routing in `app.js`? The full code of the project is here: https://github.com/patut/SCBI.

Comment: Can it be caused by this `file://file:///`? Should not be there simply `file://` or better `locahost` ...

Comment: Are you using Node to host this or are you just running the site off of the filesystem?

Comment: Looks like a similar issue to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15105910/angular-ng-view-routing-not-working-in-phonegap

Comment: Could you try to add '/' to the templateUrls,
like /teachers.html etc.?

Answer (score 1):

This could happen if the base URL mentioned in your HTML5 page is incorrect. 
Please share your base URL tage here.