# Phonegap Cordova 3.7 and Angularjs 1.3 ngRoute dont work

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cordova

My code work's on mobile version of chrome but not in cordova. I have error while trying to bootstrap application. It looks like angular route module is not loaded but all works on same device via chrome browser (Android).

in my head section

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/angularroute.min.js"></script> 
<script src="scripts/angular.app.bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers/slideMenuController.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers/searchController.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/others.js"></script>
```

in others.js:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function(){

    angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']); // <- this throws error

}, false);
```

my error:

https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=Error:%20%5B$injector:nomod%5D%20http:%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.3.15%2F$injector%2Fnomod%3Fp0%3DmyApp%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Error%20(%3Canonymous%3E)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20file:%2F%2F%2Fandroid_asset%2Fwww%2Fscripts%2Fangular.min.js:6:417%0A%20%20%20%20at%20file:%2F%2F%2Fandroid_asset%2Fwww%2Fscripts%2Fangular.min.js:21:412%0A%20%20%20%20at%20a%20(file:%2F%2F%2Fandroid_asset%2Fwww%2Fscripts%2Fangular.min.js:21:53)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20file:%2F%2F%2Fandroid_asset%2Fwww%2Fscripts%2Fangular.min.js:21:296%0A%20%20%20%20at%20file:%2F%2F%2Fandroid_asset%2Fwww%2Fscripts%2Fangular.min.js:35:46%0A%20%20%20%20at%20r%20(file:%2F%2F%2Fandroid_asset%2Fwww%2Fscripts%2Fangular.min.js:7:302)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(file:%2F%2F%2Fandroid_asset%2Fwww%2Fscripts%2Fangular.min.js:34:399)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20ab%20(file:%2F%2F%2Fandroid_asset%2Fwww%2Fscripts%2Fangular.min.js:38:135)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20d%20(file:%2F%2F%2Fandroid_asset%2Fwww%2Fscripts%2Fangular.min.js:17:381

Comment: I think this event is been calling before angular module initialization

Comment: @pankajparkar but how can i fix this?Can you give me some advice?

Comment: could you try to load `cordova.js` after all angularjs file or do `document.addEventListener('deviceready', function(){

    angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);

}, true);`

Comment: @pankajparkar yes, im getting same error. Even if angular bootstrap is wrapped with setTimeout for 10 sec.

Comment: take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/15648056/2435473

Comment: @pankajparkar i have seen this before but also does not work. I spend about 2 hours on google before adding question here ;-)