# Angularjs routing on phonegap not working

Tags: angularjs, cordova, phonegap-build, ngroute

I have this web app that has to become a app using phonegap: the problem is that we used angularjs and routing and so the views. It seems that there is no way to make them work using phonegap, I already tried [Angular ng-view/routing not working in PhoneGap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15105910/angular-ng-view-routing-not-working-in-phonegap) but it doesn't help.

This is the **index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="RoutingApp">

<head>
    <title>Big Gym</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/courses.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/navbar.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/sidebar.css">
</head>


<body>

    <div class="mainContainer">
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>

    <!--Footer-->
    <div my-footer></div>

    <!-- Include the AngularJS library -->
    <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Include the AngularJS routing library -->
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.28/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        app.initialize();
    </script>

    <!-- Scroll-->
    <script src="js/angular-smooth-scroll.min.js"></script>

    <!-- UI Bootstrap -->
    <script src="js/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.0.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Directives -->
    <script src="js/directives/footer.js"></script>

    <!-- Controllers -->
    <script src="js/controllers/MapController.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers/CourseHomeController.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers/CourseController.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers/InstructorController.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers/NavbarController.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers/categoriesController.js"></script>

    <!-- Services -->
    <script src="js/services/courses.js"></script>
    <script src="js/services/categories.js"></script>

    <!-- Maps -->
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**app.js**

```
app=angular.module('RoutingApp', ['ngRoute','ui.bootstrap','smoothScroll']);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: '/www/views/Home.html'
        })
        .when('/CourseHome/', {
            controller: 'CourseHomeController',
            templateUrl: '/www/views/CourseHome.html'
        })
        .when('/course/:id', {
            controller: 'CoursesJoinInstructor',
            templateUrl: '/www/views/Course.html'
        })
        .when('/courseByLevel/', {
            controller: 'CourseLevelController',
            templateUrl: '/www/views/CourseLevel.html'
        })
        .when('/coursesByCategory/', {
            controller: 'CourseByCourseCategoryController',
            templateUrl: '/www/views/CourseLevel.html'
        })
        .when('/instructor/:id', {
            controller: 'InstructorController',
            templateUrl: '/www/views/Instructor.html'
        })
        .when('/Location', {
            templateUrl: '/www/views/Location.html'
        })
        .when('/Categories/', {
            controller: 'CategoriesController',
            templateUrl: '/www/views/Categories.html'
        })
        .when('/form/:id', {
            controller: 'CourseController',
            templateUrl: '/www/views/Form.html'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
});
```

**index.js**

```
var app = {
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, true);
    },

    onDeviceReady: function() {
        angular.element(document).ready(function() {
            angular.bootstrap(document);
        });
    },
};
```

With this code i get white screen on my android phone, without the index.js and putting ng-app in the body i can see the footer with the css, so the directives are working but not the views. Hope someone can help.

Comment: **Solved** The problem was: /www/views/ with views/ it works!

Comment: Thanks , This comment solved my issue in 2017 :)