# angularjs with cordova routing not working

Tags: angularjs, cordova

I am trying to use routing in Cordova but is not working. All js files are in www file.

Controllers are working. When I try in url to write:

```
http://localhost:8000/info
```

it says error

```
Cannot GET /info
```

I think I write in code everything correctly.

In html inside head I have put the:

```
<base href="/"/>
```

also the name module project and in body:

```
<ng-view></ng-view>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/angular-aria.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/angular-material.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/fontawesome5/fontawesome-all.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/app.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/controllers/MainController.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/controllers/InfoController.js"></script>
```

In my app.js file

```
var app = angular.module('project', ['ngRoute', 'ngMaterial', 'ngMessages']);
```

in routes.js (the below alert it didn't works):

```
app.config(["$routeProvider", "$locationProvider", function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
    alert('routes working!');
    $routeProvider
        .when("/", {
            templateUrl: "views/login.html",
            controller: "MainController"
        })
        .when("/info", {
            templateUrl: "views/info.html",
            controller: "InfoController"
        })
        .otherwise({ 
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

}]);
```

in InfoController:

```
app.controller("InfoController", ["$scope","$http",function($scope,$http){
    $scope.info = "info page here!";
}]);
```

What am I missing and it isn't working? What to try for debug?
Any suggestions?

Comment: Take a look on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15105910/angular-ng-view-routing-not-working-in-phonegap) example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was forgotten to put in html the routes.js file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/routes.js"></script>
```

Now everything works!